# Why is Font Awesome showing a square instead of an icon?

Tags: css, sass, font-awesome

I am trying to implement Sass in my project. I have imported font-awesome with NPM and have my main style.scss file that I want to import Font Awesome in. I read through the font-awesome documentation about getting started with Sass. I have:

1. Copied the font Awesome directory into my project.
2. Opened 'font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss' and edited the `$fa-font-path` variable to point to my font directory.

   ```
   $fa-font-path: "project/node_modules/font-awesome/fonts" !default;
   ```
3. I imported the font-awesome.scss file into my main style.scss file like so and tried to implement the use of an icon but the icon ends up rendering as a blank square.

   ```
   /*How I Import At The Top Of My Page*/
   @import "project/node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome";

   /*How I Try To Implement*/
   p:first-child:before{
       content: $fa-var-mobile-phone
    }
   ```

From what I have read, it seems that I have some sort of mapping issue but everything looks correct to me.

Comment: what bundle tools are you using ?

Comment: What do you mean

Comment: font-awesome needs some otf | ttf | eot | svg | woff(2) files check if they already can be loaded or not !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can tell from your information supplied. You need to set `font-family`, that should be the file not just the path.

```
p:first-child:before{
    content: $fa-var-mobile-phone;
    font-family: 'Your font-awesome';
}
```

Comment: Also if you are using the free version and the setup function(that you aren't but may help people like me... who had to struggle through... it resets the font-weight to normal (pro only) to fix this (after `@extend .fas` add `font-weight:900`) It helped me when i finally found it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and the solution was to follow the [official docs](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/using-with/sass).

- In our `style.scss` (or app.scss in other cases) add the following:

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss";
@import "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss";
```

Add the font-path to your `_variables.scss`:

```
$fa-font-path: "~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts";
```

Note that I was using npm for package management and I installed the fontawesome with:

```sh
npm i @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```